# Remove rows from dataframe that don't contain any numeric values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an example dataframe as follows:

```
x <- data.frame(Var1 = c(NA,Inf,7,NA), Var2 = c(1,61, -Inf, -Inf), Var3 = c(12, 31, 49, Inf))
x
 Var1 Var2 Var3
1   NA    1   12
2  Inf   61   31
3    7 -Inf   49
4   NA -Inf  Inf
```

I would like to remove rows from this data frame that do not have at least one numeric value. So in this example, I'd like to only remove row 4, leaving a final data frame:

```
Var1 Var2 Var3
1   NA    1   12
2  Inf   61   31
3    7 -Inf   49
```

Comment: `Inf` is numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `is.finite` in `filter` with `if_any` to subset data having any `finite` values in a row

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
   filter(if_any(everything(), is.finite))
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1   NA    1   12
2  Inf   61   31
3    7 -Inf   49
```